# Fail to install lxml in MacOS 10.8.4

Tags: python, macos, lxml, libxml2

I am having trouble installing lxml to my Mac OS. 
I am having the following error when building it. This is the error I have when using `pip install lxml`

> /private/var/folders/9s/s5hl5w4x7zjdjkdljw9cnsrm0000gn/T/pip-build-khuevu/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:9:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found

I have installed libxml2 with brew:

```
brew install libxml2
brew link libxml2 --force
```

I'm new to Mac. In Ubuntu, it would mean libxml2-dev package must be installed.

Updated: here is the pip.log:

> "~/.pip/pip.log" 124L, 8293C
>       requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py",
>   line 1185, in install
>       requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py",
>   line 592, in install
>       cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py",
>   line 662, in call_subprocess
>       % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd)) InstallationError: Command /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>   -c "import setuptools;**file**='/private/var/folders/9s/s5hl5w4x7zjdjkdljw9cnsrm0000gn/T/pip-build-khuevu/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record
>   /var/folders/9s/s5hl5w4x7zjdjkdljw9cnsrm0000gn/T/pip-nsV0iT-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/9s/s5hl5w4x7zjdjkdljw9cnsrm0000gn/T/pip-build-khuevu/lxml

Any idea ? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there an error message in `~/.pip/pip.log`?  After installing `libxml2` with `brew`, do you see the correct header files in `/usr/include/libxml2/libxml`?  Are the `libxml2` headers definitely on your path?

Comment: @ChrisP, I updated my question with the log. There is no /usr/include folder in my machine.

Comment: Hopefully someone comes along who knows what's up.  My only recommendation right now is to make sure the libxml2 headers are accessible via PATH.  Homebrew should install to `/usr/local`, which is on PATH by default.  Can you find the `xmlversion.h` file on your machine, just to make sure it's there?  If you keep having trouble, I recommend the [Enthought](http://www.enthought.com) Python distribution, which comes with many hard to build tools (including `lxml`) by default.  I know that doesn't solve your exact problem.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisP. It is true that the file is not in the path for compilation even though I have a version of libxml installed by Brew, and a version installed with Xcode. Both are in PATH. I will update the answer below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Turn out xmlversion.h is not included in compilation path even though it is in PATH. Modify the C_INCLUDE_PATH env fix the error for me:

> C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/include/libxml2:$C_INCLUDE_PATH

Comment: Just a tip for anyone that stumbles upon this: I had the same issue and this was the fix. ```export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/include/libxml2:$C_INCLUDE_PATH```

Comment: This got lxml compiling for me on 10.9 and a self-installed version of libxml2. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using macports: export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include/libxml2:$C_INCLUDE_PATH

Comment: On OS X 10.10.2 this worked (note different libxml2 version): export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/include/libxml2:$C_INCLUDE_PATH

Comment: The different version is just because Homebrew has updated the installed package; other than that you're doing exactly the same thing and for me as well this does not work under 10.10.2.

Answer (score 21):

If you are running Mavericks with Xcode installed, you can also use:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/libxml2:$C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Comment: With Xcode 6, this command is now: export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app//Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/libxml2:$C_INCLUDE_PATH

Comment: For OSX Yosemite it is now ``export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/libxml2:$C_INCLUDE_PATH``

Comment: For MacOS Catalina it is now `export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/libxml2:$C_INCLUDE_PATH`

Comment: @AshleyKleynhans thank you, that worked for me to get the python ovirt sdk installed. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I have Python and libxml installed via brew, this worked for me after trying everything above:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/include # If /usr/include is missing
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/include/libxml2 /usr/include/libxml2
```

Note: You'll need to check your own paths for latest versions.

Since the headers are available elsewhere, and being looked for in a particular directory (spotted in the command calling clang to compile) - and for some reason the alternate place is not being picked up, I made a softlink to the right place.

Answer (score 5):

None of the other answers (exporting C_INCLUDE_PATH) worked for me. However, setting the CFLAGS environment variable to the built-in OS X 10.10 libxml2 root worked like a charm.

```
export CFLAGS=-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
```

Comment: This is the one which worked for me on 10.10.2 with Fish shell. I first opened a `bash` shell, then did the `export` listed here, then re-ran `pip install lxml` and the install finally completed successfully. Thanks Dan!

Comment: Same here, this is the only one that works on 10.10.2

Comment: In Yosemite 10.10.2, I had already installed the whole Xcode package, and nothing additional was required for me to get lxml working.  I created a virtual env using virtualenvwrapper, and `pip3.4 install lxml` installed error free.  I tested out the lxml install by scraping google's home page, as well as searching for an xpath in an xml document,  and everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 4):

```bash
brew install libxml2
brew link libxml2 --force
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/include/libxml2:$C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

there is something with the permission to `mkdir` in `/usr/` when the system is Mac EI captain. Maybe we can not modify this directory?

See [What is the “rootless” feature in El Capitan, really?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really/193379) on AskDifferent